# Excel Text Formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, formulas

I've got a table made up of a number of tabs and VLOOKUPs.  I'm just looking for a way of pulling through a text entry into a cell where there are multiple #N/A's and one text entry.

I've attached a screenshot which hopefully explains what I'm trying to do.

Column E has what I would expect the answers to be with the correct formula.  The problem is, the original spreadsheet I'm working on has over 2000 rows (and will be continually updated with more entries).  I've tried multiple IF/Or, IF/And as well as Index/Match formulas to no avail.

Not able to attach pics yet but have included a link.

Comment: Went in to edit and added the link to the top of the post but it doesn't seem to be going into the text.. will try again here..   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dilmr.png

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `ISNUMBER` combined with search to get the results that you are looking for.

```
=IF( ISNUMBER(SEARCH("n/a",B1)),"true","false")
```